# How to move UItableView section text from left to right?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, sectionheader

I found some answers of how you can move the cell text to the right, BUT HOW can I move the section's text to the right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by "section's text" you mean the text in the **header** for the section, you'll need to switch from using `tableView:titleForHeaderInSection:` in your data source to supplying a custom `UILabel` with `textAlignment` set to `UITextAlignmentRight` via `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:` in your delegate.

Comment: Thanks!Now I just have to figure out hot to place it correctly.
It's a little bit behind its items...

Comment: You'll also want to implement `tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:` to tell the table view how much space should be allocated to the label. Sounds like it's a bit large for the default size.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `-tableView:titleForHeaderInSection:`, override `-tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:` and return a custom view for each section. You can format it in any way you want.